# HTML decoding in C/C++

Tags: character-encoding, libcurl, hebrew, html-encode

I'm using libcurl for getting HTML pages.

I have some problems with Hebrew characters.

for example this: `&#1505;&#1500;&#1511;&#1493;&#1501;`
gets gibberish.

How do I get Hebrew characters and not gibberish?

Do I need some HTML decoder?

Does libcurl support such operation?

Does libiconv support such operation?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: What system are you running that on?  Do you have support for Hebrew characters on it?

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Ok, so what you’re seeing is UTF-8 data being decoded as Windows-1252 (so the numeric character references were a red herring). Here’s a demonstration in Python:

```
>>> u = ''.join(map(unichr, [1505, 1500, 1511, 1493, 1501]))
>>> s = u.encode('utf-8')
>>> print s.decode('cp1255', 'replace')
׳¡׳�׳§׳•׳�
```

The solution to this problem depends on the environment in which the output is displayed. Merely outputting the bytes received and expecting them to be interpreted as characters leads to problems like this.

An HTML document typically contains a header tag like `<meta charset=utf-8>` to indicate to the browser what its encoding should be. A document served by a web server contains an HTTP header like `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

You should ask libcurl for the `Content-Type` HTTP header to know the encoding of the document, and then convert it to the system encoding using iconv. While in your case that would be codepage 1255, it depends on the user’s system and so you should look up the appropriate functions to detect that.

(Read [Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and the [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) tag on this site for a wealth of further information.)

Comment: I'm getting characters like: ׳¡׳?׳§׳•׳?
I need to work on those characters.

Comment: And characters like: ׳₪׳¨׳˜׳ ׳¨

Comment: @embedded Aha! That’s exactly what I needed.